# Improve performance of code coming out of eval

Tags: javascript

I heard "eval" function in javascript/node.js is evil, but it's needed in our application which takes a string sent to it by a sister program in certain format and evaluate it and record the result. Yes, we can trust the string it's going to be evaluated.

The problem is on performance. The following code takes 552ms. However, I replace the `eval(...)` by `function add2(a,b) { return a+b}`, it took only 12ms.

The question is, how do we improve the performance for code generated after evaluation. Would appreciate if anyone has any idea how to improve the performance with eval.

```
eval('function add2(a,b) { return a+b}')

let start = Date.now();
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    total += add2(i, 1);
}
console.log(`took ${Date.now() - start} total=${total}`)
```

**Update 1:**

Thanks to CertainPerformance who pointed out the same code runs fast on Chrome browser.
The above snippet (with `eval` but without the wrapper of ((() => { ...}) ()` took 75ms,   12ms with the wrapper.

The Javascript v8 engine for my Chrome browser is V8 10.3.174.14.

I installed node.js v18.5.0 which uses V8 javascript engine  `10.2.154.4-node.8`, however, it's not much improvement over node v10.15.1 which uses v8 engine version `6.8.275.32-node.12`.
By the way, you can use the command `node -p process.versions.v8` to find the V8 engine version for node.js

Since node.js v18.5.0 is the latest release, I can't find a node with v8 engine 10.3.174.14. So I have to wait until the next release of node. I doubt the two javascript v8 engine versions (`10.3.174.14` vs `10.2.154.4-node.8`) will have such a huge performance difference (12ms vs ~500ms).  My guess is that node.js has some inefficiency, especially when it comes to the "evil" function "eval" --- not always evil but need to be used with precaution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

- `eval` sometimes produces a slow function for some reason (fix: use `new Function`)
- Changing variables on the top level is slow when done a whole lot (fix: declare the variables that change frequently inside a block)

If you put the `total` inside an IIFE so that when it gets reassigned, it doesn't change a value on the top level, this micro-benchmark looks to improve to the desired handful of milliseconds.

Below runs in 10-20ms on my machine:

```js
eval('function add2(a,b) { return a+b}')
let start = Date.now();
(() => {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      total += add2(i, 1);
  }
  console.log(`took ${Date.now() - start} total=${total}`)
})();
```

For some reason, the `eval`ed function appears to be slow if created inside a block. Below runs in 1000+ms on my machine:

```js
(() => {
  eval('function add2(a,b) { return a+b}')
  let start = Date.now();
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      total += add2(i, 1);
  }
  console.log(`took ${Date.now() - start} total=${total}`)
})();
```

Using `new Function` instead creates a dramatic improvement (below runs in 10-20ms on my machine):

```js
(() => {
  const add2 = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
  let start = Date.now();
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      total += add2(i, 1);
  }
  console.log(`took ${Date.now() - start} total=${total}`)
})();
```

So, consider changing your serializing algorithm to pass values such that the function can be re-created with `new Function` instead of with `eval`.

If you can't change the source that's sending the function string, and the parameters aren't too complicated, you could use a regular expression to parse the function string into its parameters and body, and then pass that to `new Function`.

Another example of the phenomena without dynamic functions in the mix - see how the IIFE version below runs significantly faster.

```js
const start = Date.now();
let i = 0;
while (i < 5e8) {
  i = i + 1;
}
console.log(Date.now() - start);
```

```js
(() => {
  const start = Date.now();
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 5e8) {
    i = i + 1;
  }
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
})();
```

That said, micro-benchmarks like these are [generally a very poor indicator](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) of whether there will *actually* be a problem when your code runs in the real world. Don't take them to mean much.

> I heard "eval" function in javascript/node.js is evil

It has its place. Though, here, `new Function` would be more appropriate (and is a lot faster in certain circumstances). The general technique of serializing a function to a string to be parsed back into an actual function in a different environment isn't unheard of - this is the same technique that web scrapers like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) make extensive use of.

Comment: thanks for looking into it.  I tried your first code snippet (wrap the loop in `(() => { ...}) ()`,  it  decreases the time from 545ms to about 449ms.  20% reduction, but I wonder if there is optimization to bring it run in less than 50ms.  
I don't know what magic is going on that makes the non-eval version so much faster

Comment: My node is of version `v10.15.1` running on ubuntu 18.04. Mind if I ask what version you are using? Thanks

Comment: Great answer and information, thanks for sharing @CertainPerformance

Comment: @certainperformance  please let me know the version of node you have.  Even with your trick of using `(() => { ...}) ()`, it's still far slower than the version of code without eval.

Comment: @packetie I was running the code in Chrome, which uses the same V8 but is still a pretty different environment. I was able to reproduce the very slow function by performing the `eval` inside the block, and `new Function` fixes it - see edit - try doing that instead of `eval`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I forgot to mention that I don't have much control on the source string (I can potentially wrap it in a `(() => { ..})()` it it proves to be helpful.  
It's strange that your first snippet (with eval) runs so fast in browser but very slow in command line with node.js (which powers my application). 
I even used node v14.17.0 and got the same result as v10.15.1